# Going from modal to modal, close first modal?

Tags: usability

I'm creating an event page that has a map with pins that you can click to view events. When you click a pin, a modal opens that shows all the information about the event, including the address which links out to either a new browser tab or the device's default map app. There is also confirm attendance and add to calendar.

When you choose anything that would take you outside of our website, we are legally required to show *a modal telling the user that they are leaving our website*.

My question is, would it be the best practice:

- to overlay the *leaving modal* over the modal that shows info about the event when you've clicked on a pin?
- Or should the *event info modal* close once you've clicked something that would cause the *leaving modal* to pop up? The only downside to this is they would have to remember what event they've chosen on the map if they choose not to navigate away from our site.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to have the container of the modal stay in place and have the content inside change when the user clicks the external link. So nothing is opening or closing—the content related to the event is simply replaced with text saying the user is leaving your website and a way to continue or go back to viewing the event information. To the user, it'll look and feel like a single modal, which is a more seamless experience.

Comment: Good alternative! (However, just for the records: a link is still a [hyperlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink)...don't let Tim Berners-Lee become aware of an abuse like that.)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the real issue is not what happens behind when showing the (modal) *leaving dialog*. It's *that* there *is* such a dialog *at all*.

If I select a link I expect to go to that what I selected...immediately. Being stopped, even if it is just temporarily, and being forced to click a second time is distracting and becomes (increasingly...very...extremely...@§$%&#! [insert curse of your choice]) annoying with time.

Placing the "you're about to leave our website" hint directly on the (then one and only) *event info dialog* is not an option?

Comment: unfortunately, our site is heavily regulated by the government, and we have to show the "you're leaving" modal.

Comment: @Jordan Which country? Just to know where I will never emigrate to. ;)

Comment: USA haha. It's health insurance, so lots of regulations.

Comment: @Jordan USA, really⁉️ The Internet was invented there! OK, agreed, the WWW wasn't but in Switzerland. Health insurance? There's an argument for them: Increased clicking causes [RSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury)! :) Not to mention the steep anger path described in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I like the option for the user to stay on the same screen while navigating between sections or diving into content.

For example, see how it works in Google maps.
If you select any object on the map, you do not open a new window or transfer to another tab, you remain on the same page just a level below.
If you want to go back you can always use the back arrow.
[image]

---

Or another option. If you have enough space, open another window nearby.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "_just a level below_"? The Q is not about where/how to place the initial "_information_" dialog but what to do with it if another mandatory "_leaving_" dialog must be displayed (when clicking at a link that leads to a different site).